# Using angularjs and asp.net, how can I alert the user if a file exists on a network drive?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I asked a previous question on SO and was told that it's impractical to use ajax to check if a file exists on a network drive.  Is there a way to do it using asp.net and then send the response to javascript so that I can run some javascript code?

This is the code that I was using before moving my uploaded files from the project's Files_Uploaded folder to the E drive on the server.

```
$scope.fileSelected = function (file) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Files_Uploaded/' + file.name,
            type: 'HEAD',
            error: function () {
                //file does not exist
                existsError.style.display = 'none';
                saveSubmitButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
                saveButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
                uploadFile(file); window.location.host
            },
            success: function () {
                //file exists
                existsError.style.display = 'block';
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: I would think that as long as the account your app pool is running under has permissions on the folder in question you could just modify your server-side API to check the new folder instead. Have you tried that and it's not working? One thing I would suggest is to ditch the jQuery AJAX stuff and instead use AngularJS's $http service.

Comment: If you can think it you can do it.  If you're just calling an API, the API will do the work for you.